# Create Model To Hold Results of Path.Combine Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

My development environment is VS19, ASP .Net Core Razor (non-MVC) 3.1 Pages, and Entity Framework Core.

I have the following Class/Model, in my Models folder, which has a single Property:

`````
````
public class FilesObject
{
    public string[] Files { get; set; } = new string[1000];
}
`````

In the OnGet() Handler of my index.cs file I wrote the following code to return an array containing a list of files in a designated directory (wwwroot\documents)

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _context = context;
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public FilesObject FilesObject { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnGet() 
        {

            var webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var docsPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "documents");
            FilesObject = Directory.GetFiles(docsPath);

            return Page();
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error: Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type string to Models.FilesObject on this line:

```
FilesObject = Directory.GetFiles(docsPath);
```

I originally tried doing something like this:

var DocumentInfo = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "documents");

This works nicely, however, I cannot get DocumentInfo back to my index.cshtml page to do anything with it, like a ForEach loop.

I understand what the error is telling me, I just don't know how to fix it.

Any help appreciated.  Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: `Path.Combine` returns a `string` which is simply a well-form string of the path(s) given. Seems to me you're expecting a list of files within a directory?

Comment: Apologies, I had copied incorrect code into my source code above.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of files in a directory, do:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"path/that/you/are/interested/in");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); // e.g. getting Text files
```

See [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8)
and [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I had incorrect source code above, which has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

> Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type string to Models.FilesObject on this line:

`Directory.GetFiles` returns `string[]`,so you need to change like below:

```
FilesObject.Files = Directory.GetFiles(docsPath);
```

Before using it,you need to initialize the `FilesObject`.Here is a working demo like below:

1.Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

@foreach(var data in Model.FilesObject.Files)
{
    <div>
        @data;
    </div>

}
```

2.Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public IndexModel( IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public FilesObject FilesObject { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        FilesObject = new FilesObject() { };//need to add this line to initialize the model
        var webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        var docsPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "documents");
        FilesObject.Files = Directory.GetFiles(docsPath);

        return Page();
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @1Zero3Tech,If my answer helps you,could you accept as answer?